# Let $A$ & $B$ be sets. Prove that $\{A,B\}$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Here are the axioms that I'm allowed to use.

**Axiom of Existence:**

There exists a set.

**Axiom of Belonging:**

If $x$ is an object and $A$ is a set, then $x \in A$ is a proposition.

**Axiom of Extension:**

Two sets are equal iff they have the same members.

**Axiom Schema of Specification:**

Let $S$ be a set and let $p(x)$ be an open sentence about the objects in $S$. Then, $\{x \in S: p(x)\}$ is a set.

**Axiom of Unions:**

Let $F$ be a family of sets. Then, $\cup F$ is a set and it contains all objects that belong to at least one set in the family $F$.

**Axiom of Powers:**

Let $S$ be a set. There exists a set $P(S)$ whose elements are all the subsets of $S$.

So, all of this is what I'm allowed to prove this result and nothing more. I think this is sufficient context based on the book that I'm using. Now, I will present my argument.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. By the Axiom of Unions, $A \cup B$ is a set. By the Axiom of Powers, $P(A \cup B)$ is a set.

Since $A \subset A \cup B$ and $B \subset A \cup B$, it follows that $A \in P(A \cup B)$ and $B \in P(A \cup B)$. We define the following:

$$\phi = \{x \in P(A \cup B): (x = A) \lor (x = B) \}$$

By the Axiom Schema of Specification, $\phi$ is a set. Then, the Axiom of Extension implies that $\phi = \{A,B\}$ and it follows, then, that $\{A,B\}$ is a set. That proves the desired result.

I'm kind of not happy with that first line that uses the Axiom of Unions. It just feels wrong. But perhaps that's just me being stupid about this.

In any case, is the argument above correct? If not, what's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the 'axiom of unions' is just a special case of Schema of Specification.

Comment: Hmm, how so? The Axiom Schema of Specification is used, essentially, for constructing subsets of a set. The Axiom of Unions constructs supersets. I don't see how you could derive the Axiom of Unions from the Axiom Schema of Specification.

Comment: Oh, my bad. U r right

Comment: I think your attempt is correct then

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying my proof :D

Comment: Wouldn't the family $F$ used to arrive at $A\cup B$ have to be $F=\{A,B\}$? It seems you need to be more specific what *family* means in your axiomatization

Comment: Yea that's why I was somewhat bothered by my use of the Axiom of Unions. So, in the book I'm using, a set $S$ whose elements are sets is a family of sets. The words "object" and "set" are primitive notions and $\in$ is a primitive symbol. I was thinking of an alternative where $U$ would be a set such that $A,B \subset U$. Then, we could just define $A \cup B = \{x \in U: x \in A \lor x \in B\}$. That would just use the Axiom Schema of Specification but I don't know how well that works.

Comment: But since that set U hasn't been given in our assumptions, I'm not sure where I'd pull that from. Unless it's okay for me to just assume that there's an underlying universal set which A and B are, then, subsets of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the formulation of the Axiom of Union should be more specific, because otherwise the concept of *family* might introduce some circularity.

> **Axiom of Union variant.** Let $f(x,y)$ be an open sentence about sets with the property $\forall x\,\exists! y\colon f(x,y)$. Let $I$ be an (index) set. Then there exists a set $\bigcup f(I)$ with
> $$ x\in \bigcup f(I)\iff \exists i\in I\colon f(i,x).$$

Now to construct $A\cup B$, we need a suitable $f$ and $I$ to apply this. (Once we have $A\cup B$, we can proceed the way you did). If $I$ is any set with at least two elements and $i_0$ is one of them, we win by letting
$$f(x,y):= (x=i_0\land y=A)\lor (x\ne i_0\land y=B).$$
So now we are left with showing that there exists a set with at lest two elements.

Well, by **Existence**, there exists *some* set $X_0$.
By **Specification**, we find $\emptyset:=\{\,x\in X_0\mid x\ne x\,\}$ which has the property $\forall x\colon x\notin \emptyset$.
Then $X_1:=P(X_0)$ is a set. Clearly (well, the definition of subset is lacking, but ...), $\emptyset\subseteq X_0$ and $X_0\subseteq X_0$, so  $\emptyset,X_0\in P(X_0)$. This shows the existence of a *non-empty* set $X_1$, but since it may be that $\emptyset=X_0$, we do not have a two-element set yet. However, $X_1$ is non-empty and so $\emptyset$ and $X_1$ are two *distinct* elements of $X_2:=P(X_1)$. In other words, $X_2$ has at least two elements, as desired.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay that works a lot better than what I did. Thank you so much!